# laravel cannot post data with ajax server status 419

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, request

I am doing a project with Laravel.

When I change the selected option of the following select element I should insert the selected value to mysql database to retrieve all the data about the selected id from the server (for example the name of the user).

This is the select element (adminArea.blade.php):

```html
<select name="employees" onchange="fillEmployeeData(this)" class="form-control col-sm-6" id="employees">
    <option value="0"></option>
    @foreach ($users as $user)
    <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->surname . ' ' . $user->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

And this is the called function (adminArea.blade.php)::

```
function fillEmployeeData(emp_id) {
    var emp_selected = emp_id.value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{{ route('adminAreaPostEmployee') }}",
        data: 'emp_selected=' + emp_selected,
        success: function (data) {
            var emp_data = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(emp_data);
        }
    });
};
```

These are my routes (web.php):

```php
Route::get('/adminarea', 'AdminAreaController@index')->name('adminArea');
Route::post('/adminarea/postemployee', 'AdminAreaController@post_employee')->name('adminAreaPostEmployee');
```

And these are my controller methods (adminAreaController.php):

```php
public function post_employee(Request $request)
{
    $select = $request->get('emp_selected');
    $user = User::where('id', $select);
    echo $user;
}

public function index()
{
    $operations = Operation::all();
    $users = User::all()->sortBy('surname');
    $rooms = Room::all();
    return view('adminArea', compact('users', 'rooms', 'operations'));
}
```

However, when I change the selected value nothing happens... and if I go to the developer tools I see the following error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 419
>   (unknown status).
>   Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
>   POST.

I don't see any alert. Someone can help me?

Comment: is `adminAreaController` a typo? because it should be `AdminAreaController`

Comment: and am unable to reproduce, which version of Laravel and JQuery are you using?

Comment: Also try clearing your routes `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Yep it was a typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP status code for the `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` is `405`

See [here](https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/master/Exception/MethodNotAllowedHttpException.php#L29)

```php
public function __construct(array $allow, string $message = null, \Throwable $previous = null, ?int $code = 0, array $headers = [])
{
    $headers['Allow'] = strtoupper(implode(', ', $allow));
    parent::__construct(405, $message, $previous, $headers, $code);
}
```

A `TokenMismatchException` HTTP status code is `419`

See [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/1bbe5528568555d597582fdbec73e31f8a818dbc/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L208)

```php
protected function prepareException(Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
    } elseif ($e instanceof AuthorizationException) {
        $e = new AccessDeniedHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
    } elseif ($e instanceof TokenMismatchException) {
        // HTTP Status code is send in the header here
        $e = new HttpException(419, $e->getMessage(), $e);
    } elseif ($e instanceof SuspiciousOperationException) {
        $e = new NotFoundHttpException('Bad hostname provided.', $e);
    }
    return $e;
}
```

So this appears to be a CSRF token issue

Make sure that you have a meta tag on the head of your document like this

```html
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Also from the [JQuery Ajax Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings)

I think that the HTTP method should be defined as `method` parameter not `type` (though `type` works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯)

```js
// Send a CSRF token header with every Ajax request
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
function fillEmployeeData(emp_id) {
    var emp_selected = emp_id.value;
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "{{ route('adminAreaPostEmployee') }}",
        data: 'emp_selected=' + emp_selected,
        success: function (data) {
            var emp_data = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(emp_data);
        }
    });
};
```

But now you're gonna get an error

> Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string

Because you're trying to return a query builder instance `User::where('id', $select)` instead of the user record itself serialized

I think you may want to do this

```php
public function post_employee(Request $request)
{
    $select = $request->get('emp_selected');
    return User::find($select);
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try to 'method' instead of 'type' . You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0

```
function fillEmployeeData(emp_id) {
    var emp_selected = emp_id.value;
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "{{ route('adminAreaPostEmployee') }}",
        data: 'emp_selected=' + emp_selected,
        success: function (data) {
            var emp_data = JSON.parse(data);
            alert(emp_data);
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a CSRF protection of laravel,
you can add csrf meta tag in the head

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and in the top of the script write

```
$.ajaxSetup({
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
   }
});
```